# Split a list into a list of list

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list

```
a = ['Jane\t10','Mike\t40','Lance\t20','Kirk\t30']
```

I want to make list above into a list of list. So it will be:

```
a = [['Jane', 10], ['Mike', 40], ['Lance', 20], ['Kirk', 30]]
```

Already doing this:

```
for i in a:
    i = i.split('\t')
```

But when I `print(a)` the result haven't change. Is there any way to do so without create a new variable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `split` in a list-comprehension:

```
a = ['Jane\t10','Mike\t40','Lance\t20','Kirk\t30']

a = [x.split('\t') for x in a]
# [['Jane', '10'], ['Mike', '40'], ['Lance', '20'], ['Kirk', '30']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['Jane\t10','Mike\t40','Lance\t20','Kirk\t30']

new_a = [ ]

for i in a:

      i = i.split('\t')

      new_a.append(i)

 print (new_a)
```

dude,figthing..